# Check if browser support min attribute of date input

Tags: html

I already have a way to check if the browser support the  `input type="date"` . There is a way to check if the min attribute is supported ?

Comment: If it supports `type="date"`, it would support `min` too

Comment: Why is it important to know if the browser supports the `min="..."` attribute?

Comment: @SarsaMurmu this is not always true . If you check on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/input-datetime) you can see that some browser have partial support that means that min and max are not probably supported.

Comment: @Progman because if is not supported I can fallback to Jquery picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like what explained in this article:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/test-if-element-supports-attribute/

So basically create the HTML element and check if the attribute "min", or whatever, is in the element:

```
function isMinSupportedByBrowser() {
  var test = document.createElement("input");
  test.setAttribute("type", "date");
  if ("min" in test) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```